# Adding a user to a database from VisualStudio

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I need to guarantee permission to another user to read and write from my database.
Most of the solutions I found online are using the SQL management server which is not an option for me to use. I am looking for a solution using Visual Studio or the sqlcmd command.

Is there anything like it?

Edit: I am using SQL Express and my database was created using the code first approach of entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [test1] WITH PASSWORD=N'test1', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF
GO
USE [AdventureWorks2012] -- your db
GO
CREATE USER [test1] FOR LOGIN [test1]
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, where do I write those commands if don't have the sql management studio? I'm a real newbie to using sql-servers.

Comment: you are welcome. you can download standalone ssms or use any another tool (for example - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/features.html)